Stuck on ggpicrust2 pathway_annotation
I'm running ggpicrust2 in R to plot the picrust results but I'm not getting plots beacuse the pathway_annotation function is not working with my data. When I practice with the examples I don't have problems, but when annotating my data the output is without any annotation (see screenshot). Any suggestion about possible reasons why this is happenging would be welcome. I'm running the following code:
abundance_file <- "path/to/KO enrichment - filtered.tsv"

metadata <- read_delim("path/to/metadata.txt",
                       delim = "\t",
                       escape_double = FALSE,
                       trim_ws = TRUE
)


abundance_data <- read_delim(abundance_file, delim = "\t", col_names = TRUE, trim_ws = TRUE)

kegg_abundance <- ko2kegg_abundance(data = abundance_data)

daa_results_df <- pathway_daa(abundance = kegg_abundance, metadata = metadata, group = "Site", daa_method = "DESeq2", select = NULL, p.adjust = "BH", reference = NULL)

daa_annotated_results_df <- pathway_annotation(pathway = "KO", daa_results_df = daa_results_df, ko_to_kegg = TRUE)

Here is the "abundance_data" input.
#NAME   PBI101  PBI102  PBI103  PBI104  PBI105  PBI201  PBI202  PBI203  PBI204  PBI205  PBI301  PBI302  PBI303  PBI304  PBI305  PB101   PB102   PB103   PB104   PB105   PB201   PB202   PB203   PB204   PB205   PB301   PB302   PB303   PB304   PB305
K00001  7316    7192    5281    7636    6565    8294    9439    6777    5110    7629    6660    6029    4345    6551    7094    6881    5693    8009    7279    9148    6343    7316    5544    6599    6146    7985    5414    4751    6898    6156
K00002  4082    5506    5074    3371    4385    2140    2027    1630    965 1514    2761    2782    1589    2198    2858    4576    4585    2483    2459    2939    969 1524    1328    1181    1935    5355    2601    1851    2121    2360
K00003  17755   14915   14802   12635   12623   20795   20328   16239   10803   17099   13490   20973   15868   18993   22415   17032   13025   11473   12019   11741   12403   15588   14140   12930   18190   23660   16465   15872   19997   23731
K00004  139 78  75  143 28  10  24  18  14  17  49  13  8   15  22  156 21  125 75  16  22  16  15  14  14  45  10  9   22  20
K00005  794 796 624 735 620 945 957 676 624 878 596 572 383 604 610 791 554 848 864 1131    691 713 606 725 688 751 589 431 755 634
K00007  2   3   5   1   4   2   5   4   5   4   1   1   2   2   2   1   2   0   3   0   5   4   4   4   2   3   5   2   5   2
K00008  3075    4065    3018    4555    3262    5438    5577    4584    2989    4626    3393    3757    2465    3851    4625    3815    2940    4618    3584    4078    3583    4387    3453    3830    3749    4608    3086    2916    4099    4085
K00009  68  150 64  69  107 177 105 242 79  108 228 109 79  95  121 69  70  124 70  217 80  82  93  120 93  279 74  77  114 89
K00010  1271    1771    1222    1987    1368    1935    2218    1745    1062    1655    1231    1492    1039    1486    1834    1603    1219    1854    1521    1760    1345    1665    1286    1553    1451    1662    1194    1173    1512    1503
K00011  267 280 217 249 205 472 409 468 254 383 404 359 218 317 426 246 230 311 353 422 346 368 306 424 311 605 236 309 347 344
K00012  21189   19149   19414   15333   16010   21326   20010   16689   11043   17547   15829   22269   17094   20006   24115   21187   16112   13516   14067   12613   13259   15922   14750   13601   18974   28422   17165   17129   21154   25349
K00013  17321   14566   14505   12266   12372   20220   19319   15858   10472   16620   13107   20641   15650   18597   21785   16637   12779   11538   11764   11360   11994   15100   13798   12617   17839   23185   16252   15641   19602   23523
K00014  16238   13239   13456   11018   11145   19965   19226   15425   10107   16099   12582   20221   15363   18081   21170   15193   12081   10849   10896   10917   11841   14912   13658   12239   17575   22445   15617   15180   18972   22718
K00015  6634    6076    4604    6209    3695    6513    7210    5307    3900    6094    3831    7015    5017    8062    9798    6714    5907    7741    12631   8207    5356    5250    4030    4890    4878    6819    5996    5929    7457    8762
K00016  1128    1113    875 1174    853 1529    1316    1261    957 1480    1390    1270    869 1195    1420    1102    924 1894    1191    1492    1281    1250    1107    1339    1101    1857    1119    1052    1471    1287
K00018  5224    4450    3465    4563    2405    4238    4241    3479    2573    3913    2068    5006    3532    5811    7335    5307    4782    6261    10967   6069    2793    3137    2417    2957    2989    4453    4256    4438    5332    6775
K00019  1194    997 850 1173    860 864 921 740 674 945 637 741 500 877 1079    996 689 1297    1093    1207    801 757 655 843 764 877 672 521 934 786
K00020  3843    3768    3096    3557    3545    14055   13218   10916   6893    11243   6905    14092   11624   12834   14541   3603    3575    4168    4689    4529    7450    10356   9761    8095    13018   13240   10531   10763   13105   17070
K00021  13299   10201   11051   7833    8137    6135    6801    5080    3586    5282    6887    6154    3852    5792    7251    12698   8842    6558    6604    7070    4226    5210    4195    4439    4863    10353   5729    4656    6108    6030
K00023  195 150 125 202 147 193 234 217 143 236 119 156 101 215 240 182 117 196 203 194 197 204 151 223 218 188 166 135 169 199
K00024  13456   14785   12889   13157   12438   21812   21036   17030   11510   17910   13418   21371   16175   19927   22776   14577   12247   11203   11994   11731   13124   16277   14686   13627   19089   24021   17049   16245   20303   24620
K00025  38  51  23  30  48  38  43  18  17  30  61  42  24  30  28  34  42  55  30  38  22  24  26  32  27  61  24  28  39  29
K00027  8243    8471    6469    8706    5552    8404    8608    6700    4878    7542    4552    8314    5776    8961    11016   8865    7447    9530    14150   9630    6454    6548    5099    5943    5930    8009    6748    6692    8843    9924
K00028  8   5   9   7   4   10  16  16  17  22  11  14  7   30  9   9   11  30  18  23  12  10  14  28  8   9   13  9   13  16
K00029  2284    2119    1609    2204    1999    2239    2421    1993    1371    2054    1994    1623    1199    1893    2055    2053    1646    2678    2206    2871    1755    1916    1535    1951    1776    2383    1526    1407    2068    1798
K00030  5532    4918    3817    4901    2665    5031    4840    4020    3016    4716    2380    5411    3878    6416    7994    5664    4747    6576    11210   6541    3407    3749    2841    3555    3621    5097    4586    4766    5965    7420

And this is the metadata
sample_name Site    Environment
PBI101  BF  NRS
PBI102  BF  NRS
PBI103  BF  NRS
PBI104  BF  NRS
PBI105  BF  NRS
PBI201  SG  NRS
PBI202  SG  NRS
PBI203  SG  NRS
PBI204  SG  NRS
PBI205  SG  NRS
PBI301  VC  NRS
PBI302  VC  NRS
PBI303  VC  NRS
PBI304  VC  NRS
PBI305  VC  NRS
PB101   BF  RS
PB102   BF  RS
PB103   BF  RS
PB104   BF  RS
PB105   BF  RS
PB201   SG  RS
PB202   SG  RS
PB203   SG  RS
PB204   SG  RS
PB205   SG  RS
PB301   VC  RS
PB302   VC  RS
PB303   VC  RS
PB304   VC  RS
PB305   VC  RS

Thanks in advance for any help!
[updated with inputs]


Data supplied as images make it impossible to run your example. It is very unlikely anyone can help you without a minimal reproducible example. Also, why is this tagged ggplot2?

@Axeman, I edited the answer adding some samples from my data. I tagged ggplot2 since ggpicrust2 is implemented on it (and I'm not enough quoted to create a new tag with ggpicrust2!)

When I tried to replicate your problem by making your dataset from the example from the pathway_annotation documentation:
library(ggpicrust2)
data(daa_results_df)
pathway_annotation(file = NULL,
                              pathway = "KO",
                              daa_results_df = daa_results_df,
                              ko_to_kegg = TRUE)

and tweaking data_results_df to look like your screenshot

data(daa_results_df)
daa_results_df$method <- "DESeq2"
daa_results_df$group1 <- "SG"
daa_results_df$group3 <- "VC"
daa_results_df$p_values <- runif(194, 0, 1)^5
daa_results_df$p_adjust <- runif(194, 0, 1)^6
daa_results_df$pathway_name <- NA
daa_results_df$pathway_description <- NA
daa_results_df$pathway_class <- NA
daa_results_df$pathway_map <- NA

I noticed that I could break it by making some data_results_df$p_adjust very small: daa_results_df$p_adjust <- runif(194, 0, 1)^6 makes it fail, but daa_results_df$p_adjust <- runif(194, 0, 1)^3 works.
